# does redactor work flawlessly in jQuery 1.9 on a production environment?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, redactor

The latest release of redactor I have access to uses the 1.7 version of jQuery. Since I'm using 1.9 in my deployment, I'd like to ask the community if anyone out there has put redactor through its paces on 1.9 (or 1.8) and encountered any issues - or lack thereof?

Thanks!

Comment: This looks really localized, you probably should ask their editor.

Comment: I ran the plugin through the `jquery migrate plugin` and got 1 warning: `JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated`